# What is the extra container with "lb-" prefix in docker swarm network? How to set up docker network not to have that?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

Docker network is created in a docker swarm, which contains several nodes, with this command:

```
docker network create --attachable --driver overlay [network-name]
```

And containers are attached to the network with "docker service create" command.

There is extra container with the name "lb-[network-name]" appeared after in the network. 
What is that container and how to configure docker network not to have that?

Comment: It's a load balancer.

Comment: Ya. I can guess from the name but I couldn't find source that confirms it in details or on how to remove. Probably related to endpoint mode settings.

Comment: why do you want to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

From docker swarm documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/):

> Swarm mode has an internal DNS component that automatically assigns
> each service in the swarm a DNS entry. The swarm manager uses internal
> load balancing to distribute requests among services within the
> cluster based upon the DNS name of the service.

It's a part of swarm architecture, you can't deactivate it.

Take a look also to this detailed answer regarding networking of docker swarm:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649746/3730077