# Docker Swarm - load-balancing to closest node first

Tags: load-balancing, message-queue, docker-swarm

I'm trying to optimize Docker-Swarm load-balancing in a way that it will first route requests to services by the following priority

1. Same machine
2. Same DC
3. Anywhere else.

Given the following setup:

- DataCenter-I

  - Server-I

    - Nginx:80
  - Server-II

    - Nginx:80
    - Worker
- DataCenter-II

  - Server-I

    - Nginx:80
    - Worker

In case and DataCenter-I::Server-II::Worker will issue an API request over port 80, The desired behavior is:

- Check if there are any tasks (containers) mapped to port:80 on local server (DataCenter-I::Server-II)
- Fallback and check in local DataCenter (i.e DataCenter-I::Server-I)
- Fallback and check in all clusters (i.e DataCenter-II::Server-I)

This case is very useful when using workers and response time doesn't matter while bandwidth does.

Please advise,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945482/how-docker-swarm-mode-does-load-balancing) I asked before, docker swarm is currently only using round-robin and no indication to be pluginable yet.

However, Nginx Plus support least_time load balancing method, which I think there will be an similar open-source module, and it is similar to what you need, with perhaps the least effort.

ps: Don't run Nginx with the docker swarm. Instead, run Nginx with regular docker or docker-compose in the same docker network of your app. You don't want docker swarm to load balancing your load balancer.